# Совмещение анимации @keyframes и opacity

Tags: css

Проблема в том, что opacity не работает...

```css
#square {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 20vh;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}

#cloud-left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: cloudmove 2s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes cloudmove {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -30px;
    right: 30px;
    opacity: 50;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <div id="cloud">
    <div id="cloud-left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну естественно не будет работать.**Вы написал opacity 50**

```
@keyframes cloudmove {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -30px;
    right: 30px;
    opacity: 50; // Внимание на эту строку 
  }
}
```

В качестве значения выступает число из диапазона [0.0; 1.0]. Значение 0 соответствует полной прозрачности элемента, 1, наоборот — его непрозрачности

```css
#square {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 20vh;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}

#cloud-left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: cloudmove 2s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes cloudmove {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -30px;
    right: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <div id="cloud">
    <div id="cloud-left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! сглупил

Comment: @Александр Незачто если ответ решил вашу проблему примите его нажав галочку.